# Change Facebook icon, when post on wall through the Facebook API

Tags: facebook

When Im publishing a post on my wall through the Facebook API and I don't set an image, de default Facebook icon appears. Someone know's how I can change this icon?

Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uLDk.png

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set an image which looks like an icon ;)